# Expect case insensitive text on page - Capybara + RSpec

Tags: automated-testing, ruby

I am pretty newbie in Ruby and we are using Capybara + Rspec + Poltergeist as the driver.

What I want to do is to expect some text on the webpage I am testing, so I have this simple code:

```
expect(page).to have_content(text)
```

But sometimes it fails because "text" can be found in capital letters or lowercase or uppercase ... So, how can I expect the text in a insensitive case matcher? Or, can I use some function to maybe "downcase" all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`have_content` actually takes a regexp as parameter. You can use the `i` flag to make the search case insensitive

```
expect(page).to have_content(/my case insensitive search/i)
```

Comment: Just to be sure... I cannot do something like:

`page_downcased = page.downcase   
text_downcased = text.downcase   
expect(page_downcased).to have_content(text_downcased)`   

Or some other method to lowercase/uppercase both compared texts ?

Comment: You can do `page.body.downcase`, but I find using regex to be more elegant.